# What is the best way to add an image and subTitle into an existing listView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

Currently, I have a listView which gets its data from an API in JSON format.  I wish to display additional information and a picture, within each row of my list...

Is there a straightforward way to implement this or would it be easier to start from the beginning.... ??

Thanks

Comment: can't you include that extra data into your JSON and use it in your listView?

Comment: _Is there a straightforward way..._ What other ways have you been trying so far?

Comment: My JSON is from a public API, which I have no control over,

Comment: @B001 I'm currently showing the data displaying two TextViews in each row of the list view.... I wish to display it in a Title and SubTitle format..   The only way i've found so far is to make a Custom ListView

Comment: "The only way i've found so far is to make a Custom ListView" - take that route (it's extremely widely used and easy to do), but instead use a recyclerview. Listview has been deprecated for like 3 years